# unable to read from file .Text format unknown

Tags: windows, file, text, fonts, notepad

I'm unable to read data from this file .. .Its a .dat file & i tried opening using notepad. But after opening I'm unable to read from it.The words are not in English . I tried changing the font ,but it didn't help. I even tried changing the format , nut still it was the same.  Can anyone help me with this please ?

The file is shared over here:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwISJR5GZQ88a29yTFZKTnJMYVU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What code are you using to try to read the file's data?  Can you provide an example of the file's content?  I for one am disinclined to click the provided apparent link to the file.

Comment: i'm not reading using any code ... i'm just trting to open with notepad .I have copied some part of the file ,which appears like this:-                                                          Ê<"¼QHÝÂJk)„ÂüQÿL}}·)ä»r’“sÁ~MQü¢Þ‰çgH—©­BSN7:¿)xN(lÅ7¹ªàgùý³Û}ã;ÉSï çpÇ
§ÚcwŠ®M†»·¨$AçØ­9¦‡ÊÐ%Qìã¶“ÊÃE
ag6:ÓˆnWì\#¶Š%PC©ì‰—¸©)°/Þ­,g¤ql;¼™!ªì<ñÙ
%BïÊzÿªµÉÑmšê]Øb´xw£× ñþmlHoc6Cßø]ƒï.%@\e<&[RÿÿTH¢ú‚†5Ä|ßÞPZÀvæ}7f]È”N{Só€g£

Answer (score 2):

This is not a text file; it is binary. It has the MIME type `application/octet-stream`.

This means you need to open it in whatever program it was created with.

Comment: I tried doing so.. but i'm still unable to read from it.Is there any other way out ?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to read it, because it's not text data. Notepad will not help certainly.
Dat files are used by lots of programs and this file may be for one of those programs. I don't know why this file was shared. Maybe it was savefile of a game or setting of another program.

So in brief, you can't open it like text data and if you don't have any other information about this .DAT file, you should let it go.